# Thread network connection issues

Tags: iot, zephyr-rtos, openthread

We have a thread network of about 40 Nordic nrf52840 endpoints and an OTBR made of Raspberry Pi and a nrf52840 dongle. End points use SLAAC enabled.

In some cases, the OTBR finds network to join but stops functioning once joining or creating a network.
In other cases, we find the network very unstable, endpoints IP seems to be changing every few seconds or in best case minutes. I especially wonder about the fact the IP prefix is also being changed in some of the cases.

We tried setting an IP manually, no connection was established.
On 2-3 devices network we hardly see those issues.